# multiple select-query from multiple checkboxes in 2 different groupboxes

Tags: linq, select, checkbox

I have 2 groupboxes, one for all types of activities and one for the languages.
Each of the groupboxes contains a number of checkboxes created out of the database with a loop.

Tag = ID
Text = Description

Now I want to use these as a filter to find out which persons give the selected activities and in the selected languages (e.g. Mountainbike and Guided trip in French and English).
So I want a AND AND AND AND selection.

tables : tblGuides / tblLanguages / tblActivities / tblGuideLanguages / tblGuideActivities

tblGuides : ID / Name / FirstName / Address / ...
tblLanguages : ID / Description
tblActivities : ID / Name / Duration / Free
tblGuidelanguages : GuideID / LanguageID
tblGuideActivities : GuideID / ActivityID

1st STEP : I make 2 list, one of the selected languages and one of the selected activities

```
List<int> lstExcursionID = new List<int>();

foreach (Control oControl in sgbExcursion.Controls)
{
    if (oControl.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
    {
        CheckBox oCheckBox = (CheckBox)oControl;
        if (oCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            lstExcursionID.Add(int.Parse(oCheckBox.Tag.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 lists now : lstExcursionID and lstLanguagesID

But how can I get the right data of out of the database? I tried different LINQ-queries but it's alwasy an OR-selection.
Can someone get me on the right track?
thx

Comment: tblGuides : ID / Name / FirstName / Address / ...
tblLanguages : ID / Description 
tblActivities : ID / Name / Duration / Free 
tblGuidelanguages : GuideID / LanguageID 
tblGuideActivities : GuideID / ActivityID

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to do a JOIN the lists but based on your description I can't figure out if they have anything that you can join on.

It would help if you showed examples of the input data.

UPDATE:

It's a draft of how I would try approaching it - this should find the guide Name/ID for a selected activity in a selected language.

```
var guide = from g in tblGuides
            join ga in tblGuideActivities on g.Id equals ga.GuideID
            join gl in tblGuideLanguages on g.ID equals gl.GuideID
            where ga.ActivityID == [selectedActivity]
            and gl.LanguageID == [selectedLanguage]
            select g.Name
```

You might perform such a query for each activity/language pair which would give you a list of guides - then you could select just distinct entries from the list.

It might need refactoring as it's hard to test it without all the data - hope this helps a bit.